# ContinueWith and Result of the task

Tags: c#

I use this code

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Task<int> t = new Task<int>(() => { return 43; });
        t.Start();
        t.ContinueWith((i) => {return i.Result * 2; });

        Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", t.Result.ToString());

        Console.Read();
    }
```

And I notice that t.Result equals 43 instead of 86.
If I print something in the ContinueWith it appears in the Console.
Why the Result is not modified by the ContinueWith?

Answer (score 48):

That's because [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) creates completely new task, result of which you ignore, and instead print the result of the first one, which is rightfully `43`. Try the following snippet:

```
Task<int> t = new Task<int>(() => { return 43; });
t.Start();
var t2 = t.ContinueWith((i) => {return i.Result * 2; });

Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", t2.Result.ToString());
```

Answer (score 15):

The other two answers are correct. There is another `Task` returned via `ContinueWith`. If you don't care about each individual step.. then your code can become much smaller by assigning the value of the `ContinueWith` after chaining them:

```
var t = Task.Run(() => 43)
        .ContinueWith(i => i.Result * 2);

// t.Result = 86
```

You will find that a lot of task-based code follows this. It isn't often that you will create and start individual `Task` instances when you're chaining `ContinueWith` on the end.

Answer (score 14):

ContinueWith will create a new task  when  the first task complete execution that's may or not use the same thread because it's depend on  the task scheduler

You can use [`ContinueWith<TResult>(Func<Task, TResult>`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order get the result from the second  task

your code will look  something like this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Task<int> t = new Task<int>(() => { return 43; });
            t.Start();
            Task<int> t2 = t.ContinueWith<int>((i) => { return i.Result * 2; });

            Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", t2.Result.ToString());

            Console.Read();

        }
```